# how to split a list in two at the point where predicate is first False

Tags: python

I keep thinking there should be a function for this, but I've searched the likely places (google, itertools docs, list methods, other SO questions), but nowhere found *quite* what I was looking for.

Naive and working implementation:

```
def split_at_first_false(pred, seq):
    first = []
    second = []
    true_so_far = True
    for item in seq:
        if true_so_far and pred(item):
            first.append(item)
        else:
            true_so_far = False
            second.append(item)
    return first, second

print split_at_first_false(str.isalpha, "abc1a2b")
# (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', 'a', '2', 'b'])
```

It works, but it doesn't feel right. There should be a better way to do this!

**EDIT:** I ended up with using a slightly modified version of senderle's final suggestion after reviewing the answers:

```
from itertools import chain

def split_at_pred(pred, seq):
    head = []
    it = iter(seq)
    for i in it:
        if not pred(i):
            head.append(i)
        else:
            return iter(head), chain([i], it)
    return iter(head), iter([])
```

It's short and elegant, output is two iterators no matter the input (strings, lists, iterators), and as a bonus, it even works with the following input:

```
from itertools import count
split_at_pred(lambda x: x == 5, count())
```

The other solutions, those that work at all with iterators, will run out of memory with this input. (Note that this *is* just a bonus. Infinite iterators was something I hadn't even considered when I wrote this question)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems like a job for itertools.

```
>>> first = list(itertools.takewhile(str.isalpha, l))
>>> second = list(itertools.dropwhile(str.isalpha, l))
>>> first
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> second
['1', 'a', '2', 'b']
```

This needs to be altered if `l` is an iterator rather than a sequence.

```
>>> def bisect_iter(pred, i):
...     i1, i2 = itertools.tee(i)
...     return itertools.takewhile(pred, i1), itertools.dropwhile(pred, i2)
... 
>>> i1, i2 = bisect_iter(str.isalpha, iter(l))
>>> list(i1)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(i2)
['1', 'a', '2', 'b']
```

The downside of `tee` is that the initial values are cached and tested twice (by both `takewhile` and `dropwhile`). That's wasteful. But caching values is unavoidable if you want to both accept and return iterators.

However, if you can return lists from an iterator, I can think of one solution that doesn't make extra copies or tests, and it's very close to yours:

```
>>> def bisect_iter_to_list(pred, it):
...     l1 = []
...     for i in it:
...         if pred(i):
...             l1.append(i)
...         else:
...             l2 = [i]
...             l2.extend(it)
...     return l1, l2
... 
>>> bisect_iter_to_list(str.isalpha, iter(l))
(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', 'a', '2', 'b'])
```

The only sneaky bit is that where there would normally be a `break` statement (i.e. after the `else` clause), I've simply consumed the iterator, causing the `for` loop to terminate early.

Finally, if you *still* want to return iterators, but don't want to do extra tests, here's a variation on the above that I believe is optimal.

```
>>> def bisect_any_to_iter(pred, it):
...     it = iter(it)
...     head = []
...     for i in it:
...         if pred(i):
...             head.append(i)
...         else:
...             tail = itertools.chain([i], it)
...             break
...     return iter(head), tail
... 
>>> a, b = bisect_iter_to_iter(str.isalpha, iter(l))
>>> list(a)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(b)
['1', 'a', '2', 'b']
```

Comment: You can avoid that by using `itertools.tee`.

Comment: If you add `it = iter(it)` to the top of your `bisect_iter_to_iter` function it will work the same wheter the input is a string, an iterator or a list. :)

Comment: Not necessary to read iterator into a list to pass it to extend, as in `listvar.extend(list(iteratorvar))` just pass the iterator:  `listvar.extend(iteratorvar)`

Comment: @Paul, good point -- I _was_ making an unnecessary copy! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
def split_at_first_false(pred, seq):
    for i, item in enumerate(seq):
        if not pred(item):
            return seq[:i], seq[i:]
```

Comment: What if pred(item) never returns False?

Comment: I really like this one. Only downside is it doesn't work if seq is an iterator.

Comment: Rename it to _split_at_pred_, check for pred(item). More natural feeling interface. You can then simply negate the predicate to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: To be honor this code will not produce correct results. Why? Since it will return a tuple of strings!

Comment: @Artsiom I did not specify in my question what kind of objects the sequence should be split into. Intuitively, I'd say when a string is used as input, it should output strings as well. Same with lists and iterators -- you get out what you put in.

Comment: @lazyr - ok than sorry - i simply guess about this because in your sample input is string while output is a tuple of list of strings. Anyway i was not down voting this solution.

Comment: @Artsiom Well, I ended up using a solution that only outputs iterators. The important thing to me was that I could iterate over the output, and then it doesn't matter if it's a string, a list or an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
def split_at_first_false(pred, seq):
    pos = 0
    for item in seq:
        if not pred(item):
            return seq[:pos], seq[pos:]
        pos += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't shy away from iterators, this is a perfect case for using one.  Once the first false item is hit, use the same iterator to just fill out the rest of the items into the second list.

```
def split_at_false(pred, seq):
    # if seq is not already an iterator, make it one
    if not hasattr(seq,'next'):
        seq = iter(seq)

    first, second = [], []
    for item in seq:
        if not pred(item):
            second.append(item)
            break
        first.append(item)

    # at this point, seq points to the first item
    # after the false item, just add it and all the 
    # rest to the second list
    second.extend(seq)

    return first, second

is_odd = lambda x : x % 2    
print split_at_false(is_odd, [1])    
print split_at_false(is_odd, [1,2,3,4,5])
print split_at_false(is_odd, [2,3,4,5,6])
print split_at_false(is_odd, [])
```

Prints:

```
([1], [])
([1], [2, 3, 4, 5])
([], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
([], [])
```

No tee'ing, no extra list storage, no iterating twice over the list, no slicing, just an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
 def split_at_first_false(pred, seq):
        index = 0
        while index < len(seq):
            if not pred(seq[index]):
                 return seq[:index], seq[index+1:]
            index+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code :

```
data = "abc1a2b"

def split_at_first_false(pred, seq):
    if not isinstance(seq, list):
       seq = list(seq)
    for i,x in enumerate(seq):
        if not pred(x):
            return seq[:i], seq[i:]
    return seq, []
```